# how to rotate a line from 0 to 180 degrees depending on position in another view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, cgaffinetransform

I want a line to be animated from 0° to 180° depending on touch (drag) position in another view. So I have a container and a PanGestureRecognizer attached to it. Depending on the touch and direction, I want the line to move left or right. The X is the anchorpoint.

```
┌───────────────────┐
│ Container         │
│                   │
│        │          │
│        │ arrow    │
│        │          │
│        │          │
│        │X         │
└───────────────────┘
```

So far I got this:

```
//fixed anchorpoint for animation
arrow.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 1.0);

NSInteger locationX = touchLocation.x * (180/container.frame.size.width);

CGPoint touchLocation = [panGestureRecognizer locationInView:container];
CGPoint velocity = [panGestureRecognizer velocityInView:container];
```

But using:

```
if(velocity.x > 0)
    {
        arrow.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate([arrow transform], M_PI / locationX);
    } else
    {
        arrow.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate([arrow transform], -M_PI / locationX);
    }
```

will move it left/right but not stop at 0/180°. And the more I get to 0°/180° the line moves faster/slower. I'm not good at math so please be nice.

Final result should be that the line moves at the same speed all the time and stop at 0°/180°.

Comment: What happens if you reset the transform to CGAffineTransformIdentity each time before you do CGAffineTransformRotate?

Comment: you mean: arrow.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
this makes it even worse. Left/Right movement is behaving strange, and it moves slower as touches reach the borders of the container.